# Injecting error in Kubernetes fake client

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go, kubebuilder

I'm using the **FakeClient** by `sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/client/fake`. In one of my unit tests, the `Update()` method of **FakeClient** should fail to update the k8s object and return an error. How to achieve this without faking the `Update()` method. Here is an example:

`data.go`

```golang
type Data struct {
    dep *Deployment
}

func (d Data) updateDeployment(c client.Client) error {
    return c.Update(context.Background(), dep)
}
```

`test.go`

```golang
type fakeData struct {
    dep *Deployment
}

func TestUpdateDeploymentFailed(t *testing.T){
   dep :=  &Deployment{}
   fd := fakeData{
      dep : dep,
   }
   fakeClient := fake.NewClientBuilder().WithScheme(scheme).WithObjects(dep).Build()
   err := fd.updateDeployment(fakeClient)
   assert.NotNil(t, err)
}
```

I want the `fd.updateDeployment(fakeClient)` method to return an error without mocking the `Update()` method of fake client.